# Dell Optiplex Fan not triggered at high temperature

Tags: dell, fan, overheating, temperature, 23.10

I noticed recently that my Dell Optiplex 7069 miniPC tends to run quite hot as the fans don't seem to increase speed even when it gets hot. On inspection, I could see that the CPU was at 90degC and the fan speed were quietly humming at slow speed (1000rpm), doing next to nothing to reduce the temperature when their max speed is 6200rpm. I have i8kctl installed and `i8kctl` returns the correct temperature. However, it doesn't seem to recognise the fans.

Output from `i8kctl`:

```
/proc/i8k format version:   1.0
BIOS version:               1.2
CPU temperature (Celsius):  68
left fan status:            -1
right fan status:           -1
left fan rpm:               -1
right fan rpm:              891
ac status:                  -1
buttons status:             -1
```

Output from `sensors | grep fan`:

`fan1:         922 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, max = 6100 RPM)`

I have checked white a few posts on this topic and I haven't seen anyone getting `-1 -1` for fan status. If I run `i8kfan 1 2` (I only have a right fan), it does appear to increase the fan speed but it goes to max speed (~6200rpm) right away and stays there. If I run `i8kfan 1 0`, it does the same as with `i8kfan - 1`. I also played around with the config in `/etc/i8kmon.conf` and changed the speed for speed(1) to be 2000rpm and speed(2) to be 4000rpm. the updated values are read by `i8kmon -v` but this also did nothing as I can only get slow mode 1000rpm or full blast 6200rpm.

I tested applying a pwm value directly to the fan pwm1
`# echo 200 > /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/pwm1` and once again, the behaviour is a bit odd. It does nothing up to a value of 191 and if I apply a value of 192 (or above), the fans does full speed again. it doesn't look like there is anything between very low and max speed...

I also tried `fancontrol` and `pwmconfig`. It did recognise the fan but also set it to run constantly at max speed. it also complained that there was "no correlation" which might be because the speed doesn't seem affected by the value put into `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/pwm1`.

Has anyone had any luck with fan control on Dell PC? is there actually only 2 speeds? as I have a dual boot, I restarted on Windows to see how it would behave. I couldn't get the exact temperatures or fan speeds but it did appear to throttle to keep the temperature down.

Would anyone have any idea bout what might be causing this issue?

PS: I'm running 23.10. I am not actually sure if this is new but I only noticed this recently.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same issue, please refer to https://github.com/vitorafsr/i8kutils/issues/38

The developer help figuring out that the option `fan_max=3` had to be added to `/etc/modprobe.d/i8k.conf` (in addition to `force=1`). He also submitted a patch to the kernel mailing list so, if you have kernel 6.8+, this should be resolved already: https://lkml.org/lkml/2023/11/22/1541

You still won't really be able to use `i8kutils` to manually change the fan speed due to a Dell BIOS issue but as long as you delete `i8kutils`, your computer's fan should automatically go into auto fan speed mode and adjust the fan speed automatically.